# Pulling name and title from strings in Python 3.5

Tags: string, python-3.x

I'm working through a list of legal notices and need to pull the name and title from the strings.

```
"NO. 17-1354 (1) THOMAS A. GOLDBERG ADMINISTRATOR"
"NO. 17-1355 (1) ASHLEY MARIE BAKER EXECUTOR"
"CAUSE NO. _________ TIMOTHY WIMBERLY PETITIONER"
"ERIC SMITH, PETITIONER NO. 17-1048 MLF"
```

I've been trying various combinations using .split(), but can't seem to find one combo to fit them all.

For each one I want to identify the name and title, so it would look like:

```
['THOMAS A. GOLDBERG', 'ADMINISTRATOR']
['ASHLEY MARIE BAKER', 'EXECUTOR']
```

etc.

Comment: is the last word guaranteed to be the title?

Comment: This is not trivial at all, even a regex wouldn't help you here. What if a person's name consists of 4 words? what if a person's title consists of 2 (or more) words?

Comment: if there is no structure to the input data, then i suppose it will be extremely hard to do this...

Comment: @pyjg, yes, the last word after the name would be the title. But in the last example, the last word in the string is not the title.

Comment: @pyjg there is a structure, it is just not defined well enough.

Comment: @DeepSpace yes, that is what i meant

Comment: @mightyoscar Unless you have a defined set of names and titles that can appear in the text I'm afraid you'll need some heavy duty tools such as ntlk, and even then I doubt you will be able to get more than decent results.

Comment: @DeepSpace There are a limited number of possible titles, all one word, though no restrictions on the names.